# How to install ORO CRM?

Tags: orocrm

I already have installed "Composer", "Git Clone" and "Node.js". Please guide me step by step to install in web server. Also if you have any video please share it to me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your System Requirement is match or not using this url: 
https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/index/current/system-requirements

second basic setting in php.ini file like

-- remove comment from

```
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
```

-- set `memory_limit=512M`

-- download `php_apcu.dll` file and copy in php/ext/ folder
-- add

```
[APCu]
extension=php_apcu.dll
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=32M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.serializer=php
```

Restart the Apache server

Then

Step 1 : Create `orocrm` folder in htdocs or www folder and `oro_crm` db

Step 2 : Go to in that folder throw cmd

Step 3 : run this command `git clone -b 1.9.0 https://github.com/orocrm/platform-application.git orocrm` (it will download in orocrm)

step 4 : run `composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev` (it will install composer and all needed settings)

write in browser URL : `localhost/orocrm/web` then start setup

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/orocrm/crm-application/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions) is a detailed instruction how you can install orocrm.