# ORO-CRM Composer Install - Failed to download composer/composer

Tags: windows, git, composer-php, orocrm

For Install OroCRM in windows i have followed -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929643/8416476 after successful the command **git clone -b 1.9.0 https://github.com/orocrm/platform-application.git orocrm**  then i try to run **composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev** Here i am getting error.

> - Installing composer/composer (1.0.0-p1): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download composer/composer from dist: The
>     "https://api.github.com/repos/orocrm/composer/zipball/833ce984264204e7d6576ab082660105c7d8f04c"
>     file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

How can i solve the issue.

Note : OroCRM in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Linux platform with Xampp for better convenient. refer https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/current/system-requirements#system-requirements

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Install composer globally using https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
Then just run `composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev` from within application folder. This error is very odd and why are you trying to download 1.9.0 version? It is copy paste error or you specifically need this one?

Comment: Ive tested and on ubuntu everything works, so you either do smth wrong or it is some kind of windows fault